# .NET WinForms: suspend code until mouse move or keyboard press

Tags: .net, winforms, keypress, mousemove

In .NET WinForms I want to display message in a status bar and suspend the program execution until user moves mouse or presses keyboard. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this in a windows forms app or on ASP.NET?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you have some background threads using a lot of CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Put your program into a separate thread, suspend the thread with

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Suspend()
```

and restart it from another thread, which is listening to the mouse/keyboard-events.

Edit:

Ok. Thread suspension is evil and not necessary here, as the Program-Thread itself enters a Suspended - better a Sleeping or Waiting state. So just wait (sleep-cycle, WaitHandle - some semaphore, whatever) for the Interface-Thread to allow the Program-Thread to progress.

Comment: Suspend is obsolete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx